# Showing Gaussian noise

Tags: matlab, computer-vision

```
im = imread('peppers.png');
 noise=randn(size(im)).*1;
output=double(im)+noise;

imshow(output);
```

It just show a white image

I hope it shows some gaussian noise on top of peppers.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should first convert to double using `im2double` (not `double`) and then add noise:

```
im = imread('peppers.png');
imd = im2double(im);
noise=randn(size(im)).*0.1;
output=imd+noise;
imshow(output);
```

[image]

**Why this happens?**

if you check the type of the `im` variable you will see that it is `uint8`. Applying the function `double` to a matrix with type `uint8` does not rescale the values but only changes the type of the function.

```
>> im(100,100)

ans =

   66

>> double(im(100,100))

ans =

    66
```

And checking the types:

```
>> class(im)

ans =

uint8

>> class(double(im))

ans =

double
```

On the other hand when we use `im2double` the matrix is rescaled (to `[0 1]`) and the class is also changed to `double`:

```
>> imd(100,100)

ans =

    0.2588

>> class(imd)

ans =

double
```

Comment: Thanks, but what is the different between this and output=double(im)+noise;?